Dropping the rest of a string from a known word's spot
Batch: I have a string in a variable %filename%. I need to check it for a known variable %year%, and use it to simplify the string into just the title.
Example:
The Grand Strategy (1999) whatever.pdf

...would become...
The Grand Strategy

...so the point would be to use the year as a cutoff point, taking out the year and the rest of the filename with it. The script would have to work for any unknown filename.
my code:
for /f "delims=" %%r in ('powershell -command "if ('!title!' -match '\b(19|20)\d{2}\b') { echo $matches[0] } else { echo No match }"') do set "year=%%r"
set title=!title: (%year%)=& rem !"


From your example, it looks like you are using the space and bracket before the year. Can you clarify? Can you show what you have tried so far?

You are missing a double quote and should we assume you have delayed expansion enabled.  Your code should always be a [mcve].

We certainly need more information about all of the possible string patterns before we could begin to offer a robust methodology. Also you have technically submitted code, with no indication of what the problem with that code is. Our job is to help you to fix a problem with your code, not to give you code to match a specific task. We are not a free code writing site.

Assuming you do have delayed expansion enabled and you do have the title variable defined, once you put the double quote into the set title command your code works fine.

Agree with the above comment. But that code was designed to remove everything from and including a pattern of: space, opening parenthesis, 19 or 20, two digits, and a closing parenthesis. You appear to be asking for code to do that for other potential patterns. That in itself is not an on topic question, simply a hope that somebody will provide you with a magic regex pattern for every possible file name you may have.

Your code will have problems if there is an ampersand in the title before or after the year. Easy enough to fix the issue if the ampersand is before the year but if it is after the year you will get a syntax error.  I think a better solution would be to find what position the year is within the string.  Then substring the title and strip any trailing spaces.

yes delayed expansion. the string patterns do not matter, they would only bring false complexity to the question. I fixed the missing quote only to see it fail. see, I am trying to replace the year with & rem to drop the rest of the filename, resulting in echo %title% being !title:1999=. I realize this is a bizarre, bit of a hack type of way of doing this but it's the only idea I've got

@Compo fine I'll post the entire thing, but bare in mind all I need is a way to cut the filename

@Bricktop, as I pointed out you only need to provide a [mcve]. Your code that was originally posted was not that and the new code you posted is not minimal. Do you understand what I am trying to convey?  Regardless as I said before I used your code for Use PowerShell to find and remove year and it worked just fine on my computer.

@Bricktop, I didn't ask for all of your code, did I? What I asked for was examples of all of the possible file naming patterns you wanted the code to cover. But I also said that we are not here to modify code submitted for one naming pattern, so that it covers all others. That would be a code request not assistance to fix a particular code issue.


It is simpler and more robust to let PowerShell extract the prefix for you, using its -replace operator:
@echo off

:: Sample title
set "title=The Grand Strategy (1999) whatever.pdf"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%r in (`
  powershell -NoProfile -Command "$env:title -replace ' *\((19|20)\d{2}\).*'"
`) do set "title=%%r"

:: Diagnostic output to verify the result.
:: -> "The Grand Strategy"
echo "%title%"

Note:

The above does not require setlocal enabledelayedexpansion.

By making the PowerShell command reference the title variable as an environment variable, $env:title, problems that could arise if the title variable's value were directly embedded in the command are avoided.



Perfect! I knew there had to be a way to do a string cut. I got so much bad feedback, trying to "ask for code" so I have to ask; Where is it OK to ask for what command to use for something?

Glad to hear it helped, @Bricktop. I think your question is fine: the goal is well-defined, and you included a solution attempt; the only thing missing is a description of how your own code fell short. Better approaches are often automatically offered in answers, such as in this case. I answered before you posted the full code, and I see that you have an additional requirement to capture what the regexes match in batch-file variables. If you need help with that, I suggest asking a new question. In either case, I suggest removing the full code from the question to avoid creating a distraction.

Taking a step back, @Bricktop: every PowerShell CLI call is costly, so, ideally, all tasks are to be performed in a single call - though that can make the CLI call unwieldy. Consider switching to an all-PowerShell solution via a PowerShell script (.ps1).

Since you asked how to do this in Batch, not Powershell, I'm providing an additional answer that is entirely in Batch.
The first "for" loop is evaluating the years 1900 thru 2024. The second "for" loop is looking for matching filenames by the year output by the first loop. This will result in the output also being sorted by year. If you wanted to reverse sort, you can change this to 2024,-1,1900.
The %Exts% variable is not used here, but carries the file extension. I'm leaving it here for reference only.
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1900,1,2024) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b *^(%%a^)* 2^>nul') do if "%errorlevel%"=="0" call :Result "(%%a)" "%%~nb" "%%~xb"

goto :eof
:Result
set Year=%~1
set Name=%~2
set Exts=%~3

call set "Suffix=%%Name:*%Year%=%%"
call set "Prefix=%%Name:%Year%%Suffix%=%%"
set Output=%Prefix%
if "%Output:~0,-1% "=="%Output%" set "Output=%Output:~0,-1%"
echo.%Output%
goto :eof

Note:
The above ALSO does not require setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
